# RabbitMQ, why don't my socket descriptors release?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I have about 30 different queues in my RabbitMQ server and about 90 consumers (as some queues need more consumers to get through the messages).
I notice that my socket descriptors count continues to increase. There are a lot of messages that go through the server almost constantly delivering 120 messages per second. I'm wondering who is not releasing the socket. The workers don't ever "stop", so I'm thinking its the producer of the message.

I am using Java Spring boot to create the messages and handle the messages as well.

Who is not letting go of the sockets? Or why do they just continually increase? is this normal behavior?

I am finding little documentation online as to what I "should" be seeing. 
Should there be 1 socket descriptor for every simultaneous publish and deliver?

The version of RabbitMQ that I am using is 3.5.7

EDIT

Within about an hour of starting the server the socket descriptors count shows about 500. It says that there are 60k available so I wont need to restart it very soon. I don't feel like it should (close to) ever need restarted.

I measure socket count by just looking at the RabbitMQ admin and it says what the total socket descriptors count it.

this is one of my producers that gets called every 10 minutes.

```
public void checkDuplicates() {
    List<Order> orders = orderService.findOpenOrders();

    for (Order order : orders) {
        duplicateCheckRabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(order.getId());
    }
}
```

this is the bean for the rabbittemplate

```
@Bean(name="duplicateCheckRabbitTemplate")
public RabbitTemplate duplicateCheckRabbitTemplate() {
    RabbitTemplate rt = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
    rt.setRoutingKey("comp.duplicatecheck.order");
    rt.setExchange("comp.exchange");

    return rt;
}
```

and here is the consumer

```
@Override
public byte[] handleMessage(byte[] message) {

    Long orderId = Long.parseLong(new String(message));
    service.getOrderService().updateOrder(orderId);

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Does not sound normal. But: Increase by how much / how fast? How do you measure socket count? What is your publishing code doing, e.g. `RabbitTemplate#someSendMethod` or something else?

Comment: added edits to answer your questions. thanks